# How do I solve this issue? Issue: our account email on the Post not equal to current logged in account

Tags: spring-boot

[Screenshot-of-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzOG6.png)

As of now I didn't try anything fixing this error because I don't know what to do...
The error that results ouf of the displayed error is in the posting of a new blog entry.
I created the blog via a youtube tutorial from wazooinc